# Expected number of isolated pairs

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

An urn contains $a$ white balls and $b$ black balls. We draw balls from the urn uniformly at random without replacement, and line the balls up as we draw them out. We stop once we draw three white balls in a row. When lined up, what is the expected number of isolated pairs of white balls? Assume $a\geq 2b+3$, so the game is guaranteed to end with drawing three consecutive white balls.

I found this problem [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/ShortRunsFromUrn.shtml), which gives a straightforward inductive approach. However, the answer of

> $\frac{b}{a+1}$

is surprisingly clean. I was wondering if there's a clean solution with a nice probablistic interpretation, rather than a purely algebraic one based on induction. Any ideas are appreciated!