# Average number of couples in dance competition finale

Tags: probability, combinatorics

11 pairs of dancers will participate in a dance competition finale. However, on the day of the competition, 7 dancers were tested Covid positive and had to be eliminated.

Given that partners aren’t interchangeable, meaning, if two dancers are left without their pair, they can’t dance together to form another pair, how many pairs on average are going to compete?

Well, I am not sure how to approach this. Best case scenario is when the 7 sick dancers form $3.5$ pairs, that is, $4$ pairs can't participate, so we are left with $7$ pairs.

There are 22 ways to select the first sick dancer. Then for the second, there is $1$ of $21$ left, to choose his pair, so ${22\choose 2}$ for one pair, then ${20\choose 2}$ for a second one and ${18\choose 2}$ for a third.

It is getting very complicated to consider all the remaining cases.

I would appreciate your assistance as it's been years since I worked with combinatorics and probabilities.

Thank you.

Comment: Along with the numbers, you also need to compute to the probability for each  case, so can you do it for the first case you were tackling, and proceed onward ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a total of $\binom{22}7$ ways of $7$ falling sick.

The $7$ sick can be made from

- $1$ single, $3$ pairs ($7$ pairs intact)
- $3$ singles, $2$ pairs ($6$ paits intact)
- $5$ singles, $1$ pair ($5$ pairs intact)
- all $7$ singles ($4$ pairs intact)

Thus the average number of pairs that can dance

$= {\dbinom{22}7}^{-1}\left[\dbinom{11}12^1\dbinom{10}3\cdot 7 + \dbinom{11}3 2^3\dbinom82 \cdot 6 +....\right]$

You should be able to complete the formula for the remaining cases to get the answer

Comment: @true_blue_anil I am getting 5; is it correct?

Comment: @Juan Manuel Prada: If there is one single, it could be either of the partners, hence a multiplication factor of $2$ for each such single.

Comment: @Pradeep Suny: I haven't actually  computed the answer. I can comment only If you show your method and computation,

Answer (score 4):

Define
$$X_i =\begin{cases}
1 \qquad \text{if pair i can dance} \\
0 \qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ for $1 \le i \le 11$.
Then
$$P(X_i = 1) = \frac{15}{22} \cdot \frac{14}{21}$$
The total number of pairs which can dance is $\sum_{i=1}^{11} X_i$, and by linearity of expectation
$$E \left( \sum_{i=1}^{11} X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{11} E(X_i) = 11 \cdot  \frac{15}{22} \cdot \frac{14}{21} = 5$$

Comment: Was asking due to differing answers due to wrong feed. Can you do this one using linearity of expectation ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4428804/expected-number-of-isolated-pairs/4429161#4429161

Comment: @trueblueanil Right now I don't see how to do that one with linearity of expectation; the condition that drawing stops immediately when 3 white balls are drawn makes it tricky.  But it's an interesting problem, and I will continue to think about it.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You are always welcome !